# Scraping data from wikipedia using Scrapy - why/when do errors occur due to processing URLs?

Tags: web-scraping, wikipedia

I am just starting to use Scrapy, and I am learning to use it as I go along. Please can someone explain why there is an error in my code, and what this error is? Is this error related to an invalid URL I have provided, and/or is it connected with invalid xpaths?

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class CatswikiSpider(Spider):
    name = "catswiki"
    allowed_domains = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat‎"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat‎"

    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//body/div')
        for site in sites:
            title = ('//h1/span/text()').extract()
            subtitle = ('//h2/span/text()').extract()
            boldtext = ('//p/b').extract()
            links = ('//a/@href').extract()
            imagelinks = ('//img/@src').re(r'.*cat.*').extract()
            print title, subtitle, boldtext, links, imagelinks


        #filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        #open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

And here are some attachments, showing the errors in the command prompt:

[image: First section on the command prompt]
[image: Final section on the command prompt]

Comment: Wikipedia is already under a heavy load, you should not even test scrapping on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Mahdi: I'm just finding my way, and I'll happily scrape elsewhere. I was wondering whether Wikipedia blocks robots?

Comment: At the time of this comment, there are already four (out of the five necessary) votes to migrate it to Stack Overflow.  When that happens, the question, the answer, and the comments all move over there. (This is known as a migration).

Comment: @Seraphina Wikimedia is a non-profit organization without any commercial activities -- even sponsored ads, just to make Wikipedia a better place for all of us. They are I guess the number 5th website in the world, however the amount of money and resources they have is much less than what Google, Microsoft and Yahoo have for example. That's why they block robots, because they're not enough resources sometimes even for human users.

Comment: @Mahdi They don't block robots. But they do discourage scraping the normal pages, [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function call before all your `extract` lines.  I'm not familiar with scrapy, but it's probably something like:

```
title = site.xpath('//h1/span/text()').extract()
```